# Undefined Index: File when uploading image to PHP But works when php and html in same file

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I had been stuck on this problem for about 3 days straight. 
When i upload an image to php it gives me an error Undefined index: file.

I read many other questions i made sure i have enctype="multipart/form-data"  in my form tag, i made sure each image name has name="file[]" but no luck, But when i try doing the html and php within 1 single file, everything works perfectly. But when i split the php from the html then it stops working.

There should not be any problem on the php side, because i can get it working if html is within the php.

Html

```
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submitform" class="form-horizontal" action="submitlisting.php" method='post'  >
<p id="result"></p>


           <span class="btn btn-file"><input type="file" name="file[]" id="file[]"></span>
    <a href="#" id="remove" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>

  <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100px;">Submit</button>

  </div>
            </div>

            </form>
```

Php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

ob_start();
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

 $userid=$_SESSION['id'];


     for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]);$i++)
        {
    $supported_image = array(
        'gif',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png');


    $path = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];

    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if ((!in_array($ext, $supported_image) )&&($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] > 1000000))

    echo "Picture[$i]". "either empty or File format incorrect, You can change the pictures later<br>";

    else{

      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"][$i] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i] . "<br>";
        echo "<br>";

        if (file_exists("rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/rent" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i]))
          {
          die($_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] . " already exists please add another file, or change the name ");
          }

        else

          {
        $photo=$_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i],
      "Bootstraptest/rent/$photo");
      echo $photo."&nbsp&nbspadded</br>";





             mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO listingpic (pic,listingid,userid) VALUES 
                ('$photo','$form_insert_id','$userid');") or die(mysqli_error());
          echo"Listing added";
}
      }
    }}



    }
        ?>
```

Its calling the error right at the first time the $File enters the php, in the for loop condition  `for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]);$i++)`

Comment: are you checking on the $_POST and not $_FILES?  Should be $_FILES['file']

Comment: Could you please post your php code also?

Comment: Just edited it with the php code.

Comment: I am not sure whats going wrong because, I got it working when they are both in a same php file. But i literally just split the code up, i copied and pasted the code, and saved into a html and a php, i didnt even change any code. and it stopped working and gave me the error, i believe its something to do with my html, because the error is called the first time $FILE is called in the php, meaning the file isnt even getting thru to the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging the problem usually makes it go away.

In your php file input following lines:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

This will output whatever comes in from your form.

Also, a good programming practice is to first check the values you get from your form. What if someone doesn't load a file to the form? Then, trying to loop through files will cause error.

So,

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
// do whatever
}
```

And, lastly, change the following to real path, relative the root - /

```
action="submitlisting.php"
action="/submitlisting.php"
```

You are most likely openning the form in the browser. Assuming some local virtual host like 'mytest.com' or maybe 'localhost' is used - your form is open at 'mytest.com/myform.php' and form handler at 'mytest.com/submitlisting.php' the action attribute of the form should be '/submitlisting.php'. If the scrpit is somewhere else - put that path there, relative from the root of the site.

EDITED:

Try adding MAX_FILE_SIZE to your form as a hidden input.

To do that edit your HTML part:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
    ...
    <input type="file" ..>
```

Hidden input before any actual file input fields.

Comment: I just tried putting in the echo '<pre>" part, i believe i put that before the for loop right? I just got Array()  just blank like that.

Comment: Correct. Now you need to find why there are no files coming in to your script. Change the path to the 'action' attribute of your form. Also add print_r($_POST); to the debug and add some input type='text' to the form. After you input some text in the form and choose a file to submit - you will be taken to your submitlisting.php and there you should see $_POST and $_FILES array with the values you inputted in the form.

Comment: I have isolated the problem already before that, its something to do with the image part, not sure why, because the full form has text input as well, the text part managed to be uploaded into the php, but jsut the images arent. So thats why i am trying to just upload the images. But its still giving me that error. But i cant find out why its only stopping the images to be uploaded when html and php is splitted. But it works ok when html and php is combined

Comment: The print_r($_POST) returns all the text with no problem, but it doesnt return the images...

Comment: Just a thought for your debugging then - why are you calling a loop for $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]??

Comment: $_POST wont return files, because they are in the $_FILES array. Review your code for working with $_FILES array and you should fix the error.

Comment: yer i kept both the print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST); the file part echo nothing. You mean the for loop? Cos thats the only way i know to upload images in a loop format, and it works before. Just not sure why i break the html part up and stops working

Comment: I've edited my answer to include adding a hidden MAX_FILE_SIZE input and for you to check again the loop through the $_FILES array.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php - here you can see that MAX_FILE_SIZE is needed, and has to be before input file field.

Comment: I am wondering if its something to the twitter Bootstrap form. Because I just tried Splitting the html and php into 2 files. Just a plain html with nothing except a form. And everything works ok but it doesnt when i put Bootstrap onto it

Comment: I've made a simple form myself. It seems the $_FILES array does work like your loop checks it. Try to add MAX_FILE_SIZE value and see if there are values in print_r($_FILES) after that?

Comment: I am not sure how to add MAX_FILE_SIZE  value tho, I only put in if the file size is more than an amount.

Comment: Edited my answer to include that.

Comment: Just tried that, its still the same. I am going to try to build up the form bit by bit with bootstrap, and test eachs single increment. And isolate the problem.

Comment: This is so weird!!!!!! I copied and pasted the html form with Bootstrap and moved them into a blank html, and that works ok....I think then it might have to be something else in the html thats affecting the image upload.

Comment: Found out the reason, its something to do with my Javascript thasts stopping the image for some reason.